# Google Maps that looks like pokemon GO map

Tags: google-maps, pokemon-go

I'm trying to create a map similar to Pokemon GO maps, using [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4txbw1/i_made_a_pokemon_go_android_theme/d5l1dds/) URL.

(http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=23.038357,%2072.529030&zoom=17&size=2160x1920&scale=2&maptype=roadmap&style=feature:road|element:geometry.fill|color:0x589b89|weight:8&style=element:labels|visibility:off&style=feature:landscape|element:geometry|color:0xbcffaf&style=feature:poi|color:0x93efd5&style=feature:poi.park|color:0x08ab91&style=feature:road|element:geometry.stroke|color:0xf6ff8f|weight:1&style=feature:water|color:0x1e8cdb&style=feature:transit|visibility:ff&style=feature:water)

But I want to show few random markers(so, they look like pokestops / gyms).
Can anyone help me understand the URL or modify it to show markers.

Also, The final result should be a URL, no xml or API.

Comment: Can you at least provide what technology your using? Also, [a minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be smashing.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're new and trying to create static maps with custom markers. Usually, you should only post development related questions, but I'll give you a hint with where to go.

The best resource for the map you are saying is the **Documentation on Static** Maps:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro

Then in the markers section, you can learn more about **adding custom markers**:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#Markers

If you encounter any issues with Static Maps, just post another question with your sample request or code and many avid community members will be able to help you :)